# How to calculate the energy supply to a cup of oil under 300 degree??

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

As I know that energy supplied can be calculated by change in temperature of the oil, E=mc(delta T). 
However, if a keep a cup of oil under a constant temperature (300 degree) for 2 hours, how can I calculated the energy supply to the oil by the heater?

Thanks

Comment: It does not matter how long you take to supply the energy. The final states (temperature in this case) matter while calculating the amount of energy supplied. What I said is not true if you are considering energy given out as radiation or other real life effects.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly an engineering question. The answer depends on the type and degree of heat loss from your system. If heat loss is zero, the amount of energy needed to maintain temperature is also zero. This is likely not the case, so you need to consider the tank, its conductivity, open or closed top, exposure to air, convection, etc. remember that heat is lost via convection, radiation, and/or conduction.

Is it that you're really asking how much heat would be lost by the system? If so, a lot more information is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So it just only depends on the energy loss. Is there any other way to 'qualify' the energy (or some kind of scientific terms) that given to the oil when its heated under 300 degree for 2 hours? Because if mention that the oil is heated under 300 for 2 hours is not very 'scientific'.

Comment: Quantity of heat calculations require knowing the specific heat capacity of your oil, and the temperature change. Q = mass of oil x specific heat capacity x change in temperature. Calculations for maintaining heat require knowing the heat loss of your system.